# How to Restrict BIRT Reporting tool to export report to Only PDF format

Tags: jakarta-ee, birt

I have migrated my **Birt** Reporting tool used in my Web application from **Version-3.2.20** to 
 **Version-4.3.20** by replacing old jar files in my  application with new jar files given in **birt-runtime-osgi-4_3_2**, and it's working fine.

now I want to restrict Birt to export reports only to PDF format,
for that I have removed Emitter jar's related to those formats and it's working.

**But** along with **pdf** it is showing options for **XLSX** and **XLS_SPUDSOFT** also to export report , I cant find these two fromats related jars, how to restrict them.

Is there any other process is there to restrict them.

Pls help me on this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Tomcat, go to your Birt subfolder under webbapps, otherwise go to eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_{version} and follow these steps:

1) Go to \webcontent\birt\pages\dialog folder

2) Open "ExportReportDialogFragment.jsp" in a text editor

3)     You will see the following line

```
String[] supportedFormats = ParameterAccessor.supportedFormats;
```

Comment that line and initialize supportedFormats with an array of the formats you need, like

```
String[] supportedFormats = {"pdf","docx","pptx","xlsx"};
```

or

```
String[] supportedFormats = {"pdf"};
```

remove what you do not need.

4) Save the File

5) Go to WEB-INF folder

6) Open "viewer.properties" in a text editor

7) From the list of #[EXTENSION SETTING] and #[OUTPUT FORMAT LABEL NAME] remove the lines you don't need

```
# [EXTENSION SETTING]
viewer.extension.html=html
viewer.extension.pdf=pdf 
viewer.extension.postscript=ps   
viewer.extension.doc=doc    
viewer.extension.xls=xls    
viewer.extension.ppt=ppt    
viewer.extension.ods=ods    
viewer.extension.odt=odt   
viewer.extension.odp=odp    
viewer.extension.docx=docx    
viewer.extension.pptx=pptx    
viewer.extension.xlsx=xlsx


# [OUTPUT FORMAT LABEL NAME]    
viewer.label.html=HTML    
viewer.label.pdf=PDF    
viewer.label.postscript=PostScript    
viewer.label.doc=Word    
viewer.label.xls=Excel    
viewer.label.ppt=PowerPoint    
viewer.label.ods=OpenDocument Spreadsheet   
viewer.label.odt=OpenDocument Text    
viewer.label.odp=OpenDocument Presentation    
viewer.label.docx=DOCX
viewer.label.pptx=PPTX    
viewer.label.xlsx=XLSX
```

8) Save the File

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. But in ExportReportDialogFragment.jsp it is like String[] supportedFormats = ParameterAccessor.supportedFormats; and when seeing into that ParameterAccessor class, it is asking AttchSource. can I hard code it as you said instead of that Class.

Comment: comment that line and initialize the array with something like `String[] supportedFormats = {"pdf"};`

Comment: Thank you Laura. Now it's working, and now it's showing pdf optioon only while exporting report, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Hi, now in my report design page(some.rptdesign) in        **XML Source** tab                                                     <report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.20" id="1">  in this line if I change version to **4.3.2** it saying **no report design exist** while generating report, is there any where changes need to be done or

Comment: how to change version in XML Source to Version 4.3.2,                                                if I edit my report page, the version changing by default to 3.2.23(saying current version) and Report not generating,then if I change version to 3.2.20 then report is generating.

Comment: Hi Laura please helpl me on this, How to change  birt version in Report Design page inside **XML Source** tab permanantely to 4.3.2 instead of instead of 3.2.20.                                     when saving after changing design page it is changing to 3.2.23 and report is not generating and if I change it to 3.2.20 then it's generating.                                                               How to change it to 4.3.20 permanantely.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, haven't been at work these days. If you create a new report, what version does it have set? I think you might need to create new reports and copy the contents, since you might need to do some changes in order for the reports created in the older version to work in the new one.

Comment: Hi, actually I have created a new question for this and got answer.   Thank you. :)